# Passing complete object to AngularJS filter Comparator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, filtering

I'm using angular's `$filter("filter")` to filter an array o objects. Since I have a complex filtering I decided to define a comparator. Nonetheless, inside my comparator only the attributes that appear on the filtering expression are available

```
var array = [
    {"id": 1, "placeId":253, "name":"John"},
    {"id": 2, "placeId":253, "name":"Jane"},
    {"id": 3, "placeId":32, "name":"Mike"},
    {"id": 4, "placeId":89, "name":"Ana"}
];

var awesomeFiltering = function(){
    return $filter("filter")(array, {"placeId":253}, function(actual expected){
        // "actual" brings only the value for placeId attribute!
        // How do I access attribute "name", for example?
    });
};
```

How can I acces the other attributes from the object inside the comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comparator` is used only for the values retrieved from your defined expression `{"placeId":253}`. Since your expression only includes `placeId` that is the only value you can retrieve in the `comparator`.

However you can just use a custom filter `expression`, without using a `comparator` for complex filtering.

```
var awesomeFiltering = function(){
    return $filter("filter")(array, function(value, index, array){
        return value.placeId === 253 && value.name === "John";
    });
};
```